# Dataframe.applymap trips over NaT in certain cases?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas version 23.4

I think applymap is trying to apply a vectorized version of my function to a whole column but is getting confused when that column contains NaT.

For example.  I create a dataframe with a single column containing a valid timestamp and an NaT.  I then applymap a function that should isoformat the datetime, split it at the 'T', take the time component of that and pass it through a regex to trim off any digits past the milliseconds.

```
import re
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([[pd.Timestamp.now()], [pd.NaT]], columns=['T'])
df.applymap(lambda x:
    x if pd.isnull(x) or not hasattr(x, 'isoformat') else 
    re.sub(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\d*', r'\1', x.isoformat().split('T')[1]))
```

The result of running this is...

```
    T
0   10:25:08.686000
1   NaT
```

(I would expect to see 10:25:08.686 if the regex was running).

What appears to have happened is the x.isoformat().split('T')[1] has been run on the series but the regex has failed to run on the resulting series because it contains a null.

If a '*' is appended to the function body, this seems to force applymap onto the correct path (though at the expense of having a * at the start of the string)...

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 
      x if pd.isnull(x) or not hasattr(x, 'isoformat') else 
      ('*'+re.sub(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\d*', r'\1', x.isoformat().split('T')[1])))
```

...gives...

```
    T
0   *10:25:08.686
1   NaT
```

If the column does not contain any NaTs then all is well.

Comment: In trying to reproduce I get `'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'isoformat'`, which would seem to be the source of your issue. I'm not sure how it's ever working.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I made a slight edit to import pandas library.  What version of pandas are you running with?

Comment: 24, possibly that's the difference